# Make the desktop report the OS X version

Tags: macos, utilities

I have to maintain several different versions of OS X for testing, and it would be nice to know at a glance which version of OS X is on a machine.

I've previously created custom backgrounds with the version number, but as the number of machines increases this is becoming difficult to maintain.

Is there a utility that can display the OS X version on the screen at all times, or automatically change the background image to a generated image containing the OS X version on each boot (or, I suppose, when run manually)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `sw_vers -productVersion` will return the OS version.

You could then use something like [GeekTool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/) to output the result of a shell script to the desktop.

GeekTool is having issues under Lion right now, but the author posted [an 'experimental' build for Lion](http://t.co/2ZLCQUm). on his [Twitter page](http://www.twitter.com/geektool).

Answer (score 3):

You could create a login script that takes the output from `sw_vers` and then composes it onto a stock background with something like ImageMagick. Or if you want to skip that you could pre-compose all the backgrounds you need. Then change the background with `defaults` or Apple Events ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431205/how-can-i-programatically-change-the-background-in-mac-os-x)).